# `j` doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use data.table where my `j` function could and will return a different number of columns on each call.  I would like it to behave like `rbind.fill` in that it fills any missing columns with `NA`.

```
fetch <- function(by) {
    if(by == 1)
        data.table(A=c("a"), B=c("b"))
    else
        data.table(B=c("b"))
}
data <- data.table(id=c(1,2))
result <- data[, fetch(.BY), by=id]
```

In this case 'result' may end up with two columns; A and B.  'A' and 'B' was returned as part of the first call to 'fetch' and only 'B' was returned as part of the second.  I would like the example code to return this result.

```
  id    A B
1  1    a b
2  2 <NA> b
```

Unfortunately, when run I get this error.

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, , fetch(.BY, .SD), by = id) : 
j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group
```

I can do this with `plyr` as follows, but in my real world use case `plyr` is running out of memory.  Each call to `fetch` occurs rather quickly, but the memory crash occurs when `plyr` tries to merge all of the data back together.  I am trying to see if `data.table` might solve this problem for me.

```
result <- ddply(data, "id", fetch)
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

DWin's approach is good.  Or you could return a `list` column instead, where each cell is itself a vector. That's generally a better way of handling variable length vectors.

```
DT = data.table(A=rep(1:3,1:3),B=1:6)
DT
   A B
1: 1 1
2: 2 2
3: 2 3
4: 3 4
5: 3 5
6: 3 6
ans = DT[, list(list(B)), by=A]
ans
   A    V1
1: 1     1
2: 2   2,3     # V1 is a list column. These aren't strings, the
3: 3 4,5,6     # vectors just display with commas

ans$V1[3]
[[1]]
[1] 4 5 6

ans$V1[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6

ans[,sapply(V1,length)]
[1] 1 2 3
```

So in your example you could use this as follows:

```
library(plyr)

rbind.fill(data[, list(list(fetch(.BY))), by = id]$V1)
#     A B
#1    a b
#2 <NA> b
```

---

Or, just make the list returned conformant :

```
allcols = c("A","B")
fetch <- function(by) {
    if(by == 1)
        list(A=c("a"), B=c("b"))[allcols]
    else
        list(B=c("b"))[allcols]
}
```

Comment: rbind.fill(.data.table) should really be the default behavior

Comment: @eddi I don't see how it could be implemented, unfortunately. `data.table`'s speed comes from making a guess after the first group's result is known. At that point the (guessed) number of rows and columns is allocated in advance. Then populated directly as grouping commences. The `rbind.fill` feature needs all the results in advance to know all the columns returned.

Comment: @eddi If a subsequent `j` returns a column name not seen before, I suppose it could add that column to the result by reference (with NA populated for previous groups) on the fly.  Maybe it is doable then.

Comment: @eddi If I've understood that, could you file a feature request then please?

Comment: filed - [FR #4943](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4943&group_id=240&atid=978)

Comment: Just to add that, with a newer version of `data.table`, one can now use `rbindlist(data[, .(.(fetch(.BY))), by=id]$V1, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)`

Comment: @MattDowle I have the same problem. I'm evaluating a function within a data.table by groups, outputting a vector o different sizes for each group.
Instead of lists How can I just create a new row for each element of the vector?.
I've tried with t(), with list(list()), with as.data.table(), cbind() and many other combinations.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two approaches. The first roughly follows your strategy:

```
data[,list(A=if(.BY==1) 'a' else NA_character_,B='b'), by=id]
```

And the second does things in two steps:

```
DT <- copy(data)[,`:=`(A=NA_character_,B='b')][id==1,A:='a']
```

Using a `by` just to check for a single value seems wasteful (maybe computationally, but also in terms of clarity); of course, it could be that your application isn't really like that.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm evaluating a function within a data.table by groups, myDT[,fun(.SD),ID] outputting a vector o different sizes for each group. Instead of lists How can I just generate a new row for each element of the vector?. I've tried with t(), with list(list()), with as.data.table(), cbind() and many other combinations.

Comment: @skan It's probably worth posting your problem as a reproducible example in a new question. I don't think we can debug it based on your description in the comment alone (since it sounds to me like it should work already)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
            data.table(A=NA, B=c("b"))
```

@NickAllen: I'm not sure from the comments whether you understood my suggestion. (I was posting from a mobile phone that limited my cut-paste capabilities and I suspect my wife was telling me to stop texting to S0 or she would divorce me.)  What I meant was this:

```
fetch <- function(by) {
    if(by == 1)
        data.table(A=c("a"), B=c("b"))
    else
        data.table(A=NA, B=c("b"))
}
data <- data.table(id=c(1,2))
result <- data[, fetch(.BY), by=id]
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I am looking for.  I am trying to apply a function to a data table which would result in another data table.

Comment: Then I must have asked the wrong question. :)  I don't want to manually create a data table that looks like that.  That's just an example of what I want to do.  Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Maybe if I describe my real use case it will help.  My fetch() function from above makes a web service call that pulls back some JSON data about events; concerts, sports, etc.  An event can have 1 or more performers.  I take the JSON data for each event and flatten it into a data table.  The first event may have 3 columns; event_id, performer_1, performer_2.  The second event may have 2 columns; event_id, performer_1.  So I need to merge all these events together in a single data frame.  Since the second event does not have a second performer, it should have NA in the performer_2 column.

Comment: @NickAllen What about sticking performer in a `list` column, as in my answer?  Or keep it in long format rather than wide. Or if you know in advance the most columns that will be returned, then make it regular using something similar to the end of my answer.

Comment: Yes, those are good ideas.  I think it would not be feasible to train with this data kept 'wide'.  But keeping it 'long' might be doable.  Thanks